# Order collection by multiple columns and based on another array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a collection that needs to be ordered by multiple columns where one of the columns is based on another array and another that dictates if it should be after another.

First the collection:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {
     all: [
       App\Item {
         id: 25,
         name: "Mossie Muller",
         pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {
           related_id: 3,
           item_id: 25,
           cardinal: 4,
           period: hours,
           after_item_id: null,
         },
       },
       App\Item {
         id: 5,
         name: "Dr. Verda Rice",
         pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {
           related_id: 3,
           item_id: 5,
           cardinal: 2,
           period: "days",
           after_item_id: null,
         },
       },
       App\Item {
         id: 88,
         name: "Virgie Graham",
         pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {
           related_id: 3,
           item_id: 88,
           cardinal: 12,
           period: "hours",
           after_item_id: 5
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

Ihe columns involved in ordering are `cardinal`, `period`, `after_item_id`

The order of `period` (as you must've guessed) is based on this array:

`$periods = ['minutes','hours','days','weeks']`

I think I can use the index of the array above to order by that then order  each `period` group by `cardinal` which is fairly simple. Trying to find a way to then include `after_item_id` to finalize the ordering.

The ordered collection would in the above example be:

`ids: 25, 5, 88`

Comment: You can pass your own sorting callback to the sort method.

Comment: I would sort in database, its much quicker than getting x amount of data and sort it afterwards via PHP...